Piecewise Continuity enough to ensure finite Fourier coefficients?
Let's consider the function $s(x)$ for which we want to find its Fourier series.
The fourier coefficients are given by:
$\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} s(x) cos(kx) dx$ and $\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} s(x) sin(kx) dx$
In a book I'm reading, the author states that for Fourier coefficients to be well defined, we just need the original function $s(x)$ to be piecewise continuous on $[-\pi, \pi]$.
However, I was thinking of the function $ s(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$, which has a discontinuity at $x=0$.
The integrals $\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} \frac{1}{x^2} cos(kx) dx$ or $\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} \frac{1}{x^2} sin(kx) dx$ do not converge for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Hence, how can the author's statement be true?

It is not clear what you are asking. What has piecewise continuity got to do with $s$???

@copper.hat I've just added some more information. I hope it's clear now.

Check what is the definition of piecewise continous. You will see the function needs to be bounded in the beginning.

The function $s(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ is not piecewise continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]$, because it is not even defined at $x=0$.
Even if one defined $s(0)=c$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$, this function is still not piecewise continuous, because most definitions ask for the function to have a finite limit at all the endpoints of the subdomains that determine the piecewise definitions. As $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}=+\infty$ this clearly is not the case.
More generally, for the Fourier coefficients to be well defined, one only needs the function to be Lebesgue Integrable on $[-\pi,\pi]$; for instance, we could perfectly find the Fourier series for $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

I think that you're right, w.r.t. the boundedness/finiteness of the limit. In the book, it seems that existence of limit, implies the limit being finite.
